# Unity UI's Image component renders without anti-aliasing?

Tags: unity, gui, antialiasing

I tried the sprite's import settings with **point filtering**, with **billinear filtering**, I also tried changing my canvas' UI Scale mode to **Screen Space - Camera**, but nothing seems to fix it.

I also tried scaling it up and down, but it rendered with these edges all the time.

How could I smoothen it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The antialiasing Unity implements by default is Multi-Sample AA. This type of antialiasing is only effective at fixing geometry aliasing, along the edges of polygons. Aliasing inside a single polygon, due to texture sampling or shader calculations, is completely invisible to MSAA, so that part is up to you to anti-alias. Have you tried enabling mipmaps in addition to your bilinear (or even trilinear) filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DMGregory pointed it out, in the **asset's import settings** I have to

- enable **Generate Mip Maps**,
- and have a **Filter Mode** at least **Bilinear**.

The result with **Mip Maps and Bilinear** filtering:

[image]

With **Mip Maps and Point** filtering:

[image]

With **only Point** filtering:

[image]

And with **only Bilinear** filtering:

[image]

Comment: For context as to why this happens: it looks like your source asset is much, much larger than the size you're displaying it on-screen. So when bilinear filtering tries to smooth it, it's only smoothing within a 2x2 block of texels in the source texture, which might be just a fraction of a pixel at your display size, so it's not enough to properly average the colour over the domain of the whole display pixel. By turning on mipmaps, Unity generates versions of the image at half, quarter, eighth, etc. sizes, and chooses the closest one to read from, so the filtering is better matched to the size.

Comment: That said, you'll get the crispest results if you can size your source assets to be exactly the size you want them displayed on screen. Then there's no filtering/blurring happening at runtime, just 100% the pixels the artist authored, straight to the player's eyes.